# How to remove configuration profile ios 10?

Tags: iphone, ios

Can't remove configuration profile installed from http://altel.kz/mconfig

When i go to "Settings > General > Profile > Altel internet" there's no DELETE button.

How can i remove that profile?

Comment: Reset all network settings.

Comment: Reseted all network settings except that profile...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The profile's removal setting is set to ‘Never’, so the profile cannot be removed by the user from settings once installed.

[image]

If you have a backup of your device made before you installed the profile, you can restore the backup. Profiles are restored from a backup so if you make a backup now that will be no use.

You may be able to use Apple Configurator to remove the profile (available on the Mac App Store). Connect your device over USB and open the device in Configurator, then go to Actions → Remove → Profiles… and select the profile to remove.

Comment: Thank you, but how can i remove ios profile on a Mac?

Comment: @Alexander I presume you meant remove the iOS profile from your iOS device using a Mac, so I've expanded my answer. If you meant removing an iOS profile you've installed on your Mac itself, go to System Preferences → Profiles.

Comment: Removed, disappeared on the phone, but in configurator i still see it: https://yadi.sk/i/3RuJR9Da3Bpr9f

Comment: I just had to restart Apple configurator, thank you, bro!

Comment: @Alexander Once it doesn't show on the phone, it's gone. Configurator holds its own cache of profiles, so restarting Configurator will cause it to disappear completely as you found out!

Comment: very useful program, indeed. Why hey didn't add this functionality to iTunes?